# How has SOFU ruined/changed your life?

Tags: discussion, addiction

How has SOFU changed/ruined your life?

For me, in one simple way - I want to vote on EVERYTHING.

I read comments on a blog, and I want to say "Yup, I agree" or "Wrong!".

If I were to ever design/write any kind of website/software with comments, they would be just like SOFU's...

Comment: I missed a train once trying to finish an answer.  It didn't ruin my life though, and I'd say you have a bit too much invested if you feel it is capeable of ruining your life...

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addiction

Comment: @Jared - Not just blog comments; TV shows, restaurants (vote to close), shopping and products (meta), conversations (flag for moderator attention), politics (closed - exact duplicate), co-workers (flair), schedules (6-8 weeks), meetings (community wiki), pet choices, breakfast cereal... everything looks like a future Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I totally agree on wanting to "+1" everything.

As for how else it's changed my life... people have never asked me to wear sock puppets before... I've never had people interested in when I sleep, etc...

Basically I transferred my newsgroup addiction to SO, so there's not quite as much change in terms of time as you might think... although I do generally spend more time on SO than I did on the newsgroups.

Comment: I would upvote if I didn't reach my cap, but I can agree on the addiction transfer. I just killed my IRC/MSN/Twitter/Facebook addiction and then **bang** SO arrived.

Comment: +1, completely agree with this post

Answer (score 15):

I spend too much time creating Photoshopped images as gags, only to find out that the questions they pertain to have been closed.  Thanks, Meta!  You ruined my life!

[Jon Skeet's Newest Book http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/5088/linqso.png](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/5088/linqso.png)

Comment: Here's the question: http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/5102/48253424.png

Answer (score 15):

I have virtually **zero tolerance** for traditional, threaded-style discussion now.

Unfortunately, that's 95% of the information online.

Comment: I came here after frequenting daniweb.com for ages... Could never go back to that style... plus the experts were rude.

Comment: Same here. Whenever I visit an old forum, I'm bored by the tons of unnecessary information, and always looking for the downvote button.

Answer (score 12):

I often see food sitting out on the counter (that isn't mine) and think to myself, "This should be Community Wiki..."

Comment: Just "edit" it enough times.

Answer (score 10):

Life... What life? According to my wife I need one.

Seriously thought I can relate to the voting thing. I actually wanted to do this on a specification document I was reading at work today.

**Positives**

- More attention to detail when providing information
- Improved ability to search for information
- Learning new technologies
- More critical of information
- Only look at the Trilogy as a source of information

*With regards to the last one. I will skim other forums or sources of information, but spend time reading a Trilogy post.*

**Negatives**

- No time left during the day
- Distraction at times
- Wanting to close conversations as subjective and argumentative

I must admit I also enjoy the interaction on Meta, although at times it can get out of hand.

Comment: Totally agree with you on this one ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**I spend too much time making graphs based on data dumps.**

But it is fun, I can't help myself.

[alt text http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/stack-overflow-graph.jpg](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/stack-overflow-graph.jpg)

Comment: So wait, the purple dot has a happy face? And a tail?

Comment: Probably another case of spending way too many cycles on Meta. Yet *again.*

Comment: Yup.  Sorry, I don't have your supreme paint skillz.  Is the tail too small?

Comment: Creature first, then we'll work out if the tail is the correct size.

Answer (score 3):

The good news is, there are some places that do have voting! If you frequent places like slashdot or YouTube. But I have to agree, I constantly think to myself: "I agree with that comment! +1" though sadly, I can't.

Answer (score 2):

[My future self was stalked and brutally murdered because of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/11498/comments).

Comment: I find it suspicious that Welbog didn't reveal the identity of your future stalker.  What is future-Welbog trying to hide?

Answer (score 1):

The free telerik tools are nice...

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't ruined it because (hopefully) I know better -- but I have found some very thoughtful and helpful answers / discussions from time to time, and it's fun to weigh in on the easy ones.

Answer (score 1):

I started thinking that it would be nice to be able to edit (already sent) emails in my webmail client (to enrich / correct them, etc...).

Don't think I had that before using stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow hasn't ruined my life. [That's TV Tropes' role](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife).

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow, SuperUser and Meta hasn't ruined my life...I mean, not by now...but at the next deadli...HOLY S&$% THAT WAS YESTERDAY!

;)

Answer (score 0):

I asked a technical question on Google groups a couple of days ago and i'm still waiting an answer!
I really CAN'T accept it anymore.

Thanks Stack Overflow to have ruined my life.