# What online social alternatives to SO exist for when one's programming/career questions don't meet SO guidelines?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that aren’t programming questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions)
>   [How has SOFU ruined/changed your life?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/how-has-sofu-ruined-changed-your-life)

S.O. guidelines state that a question should be:

•detailed and specific

•written clearly and simply

•of interest to other programmers

No doubt all of us have urges at times to ask questions that are broader, more subjective or more personal yet we want to get responses from other programmers who are of the quality and calibur of the ones on stackoverflow . That's probably not a practical desire because the rigidity of SO's rules no doubt enforce the quality of the community, but... there are no doubt other alternatives out there when we want to discuss something less granular than what SO was meant for.

In that spirit, here is an initial list of good, semi-anonymous programming websites where you can ask broader questions when you feel the impulse or need to. Other resources (IE IRC channels or whatever) would also be welcome. Could we try to expand this list?

www.reddit.com/r/programming

news.ycombinator.com

forums.somethingawful.com (find the coding section)

Comment: FYI - community wiki - there's a checkbox underneath where you type your question labelled "community wiki" - just tick it ;-)

Comment: Thank! Done.

Is this type of question likely to survive under the "subjective" tag as a CW?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 0):

Could always opt for creating a [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com) site and allow for more discussion like topics...